# Perfrom action based on user input without custom dialog in filemaker

Tags: concurrency, global-variables, filemaker

I am developing a database solution in Filemaker Pro 16. I have a "customers" and "projects" table.

What I want to achieve is the following:

1. User clicks on a button
2. New window appears in which the user selects a customer from a drop down list
3. New project will be created
4. New window appears in which the user can enter the project information.

How can I do this. One can think, of course of an additional table in which temporary values are stored. In that case, I can store my customer selection in this table. However, what about concurrency. What if two people are going to add a project at the same time? In that case you would need a temporary values table for each user.

The most straightforward solution would be to directly store the selected customer in a variable. However, I don't think you can do that.

PS: I don't want to use a Custom Dialog. In that case, I think, you cannot add a drop down list.

Hope someone can help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Popover button for your customer selection. 
Place your Drop Down list in the Popover panel, and store the Customer ID in a global field (they are local for each user).

Perform your script and navigate to your project layout upon selection, for instance using an OnObjectModify Script Trigger.

Comment: How exacly do I do this. When I create a drop down list, I have to display data from a table. Filemaker does not allow me to link it to a variable. Or do you mean I should make a separate table to store my global variables (or fields)?

Comment: Not variable, use a global field in any table and attach the drop down list to it.